# Element can't be found with xpath

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, jupyter-notebook, automation

I am trying to log into company site and then automate my workflow on the site. so far the script I created using pythons selenium will login but after that it has problems finding the element that I want clicked. Note I am doing this on jupyter notebook.

The is my selenium/Python code I used to automate workflow:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Create an instance of the web driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Change to the appropriate web driver (e.g., Firefox(), 
Safari(), etc.)

# Open a webpage
driver.get('https://3gissvrdev.xxxxxxxxx.com/3GISWebJS/')

# Find an element and click it
user_name =  driver.find_element("id", "usernameField") 
user_name.send_keys("CarpenCD")

pw=driver.find_element(By.ID, "passwordField")
pw.send_keys("xxxxxxx")


SigninButton=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id=\"signinButton\"]")
SigninButton.click()

#use this section of code to give time for web page to load after logging on
in1=input('are you ready to move on')
if in1 == 'y':
Query=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id=\"d481e7896cf443e3aae933d31fc5a1d4\"]/paper-button/span")
Query.click()

# Close the browser
#driver.quit()
```

This is the html script for the button I want to click seen below:
[image]

I then copy the xpath of the high-lighted code in the picture above and put that path in the  selenium/python script for the query variable of the code as seen in the first example above.

What could be causing the error seen below. Everything works until after the login button is clicked. Note: the login click doesn't open a different page/tab and the domain pre-login is the same after login

```
NoSuchWindowException                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a0b3b1283d5d> in <module>
     23 in1=input('are you ready to move on')
     24 if in1 == 'y':
---> 25     Query=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//* 
[@id=\"d481e7896cf443e3aae933d31fc5a1d4\"]/paper-button/span")
     26     Query.click()
     27 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py 
in find_element(self, by, value)
    829             value = f'[name="{value}"]'
    830 
--> 831         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value}) 
["value"]
    832 
    833     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value: Optional[str] = None) -> 
List[WebElement]:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py 
in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    438         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    439         if response:
--> 440             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    441             response["value"] = self._unwrap_value(response.get("value", None))
    442             return response

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    243                 alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    244             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # 
type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 245         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
  (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.127)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00BA8893+48451]
    (No symbol) [0x00B3B8A1]
    (No symbol) [0x00A45058]
    (No symbol) [0x00A2D073]
    (No symbol) [0x00A8DEBB]
    (No symbol) [0x00A9BFD3]
    (No symbol) [0x00A8A0B6]
    (No symbol) [0x00A67E08]
    (No symbol) [0x00A68F2D]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E08E3A+2540266]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E48959+2801161]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00E4295C+2776588]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C32280+612144]
    (No symbol) [0x00B44F6C]
    (No symbol) [0x00B411D8]
    (No symbol) [0x00B412BB]
    (No symbol) [0x00B34857]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76717D59+25]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77DBB74B+107]
    RtlClearBits [0x77DBB6CF+191]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the above error, it says that the window you are accessing while logging in and the window you are trying to access are different, and the previous one was closed. So to switch to the currently active window, use this code:

```
def switch_window(index: int):
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[index])
```

Pass the index as -1, so your driver will point to the last window that got opened, and you can access the element in it. Once after logging in, call and use this function.

Comment: This doesn't work in my case because after logging in to site, nothing is added to the driver.window_handles .I printed out the window_handles list and its unchanged from beginning to end.

Comment: Check for any frames or iframes in the HTML page; they may also be a reason for the error. If the frame tag is available on the page, you need to switch between frames to access the elements.